# Column permutation in Matlab, keeping the eigenvalues intact

Tags: permutation

I want to generate B from A using the permutation matrix P (in MATLAB). Any help is appreciated.

```
A =
           -2            0            0            0           -4
         4.75           -5            0            0            0
            0        0.167       -0.167            0            0
            0            0            2           -2            0
            0        0.025      0.02333        0.035      -0.1125

P = [4 5 2 3 1]; % Column permutation
B =
      -0.1125      0.02333        0.035            0       0.0225
            0       -0.167            0            0        0.167
            0            2           -2            0            0
           -4            0            0           -2            0
            0            0            0         4.75           -5
```

Comment: I meant both A and B will have same eigenvalues.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors

Comment: omg so sorry, you're right.

Comment: T = [0 0 0 0 1; 0 0 1 0 0; 0 0 0 1 0;1 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0];
Ap = T*A*inv(T)